# UICollectionView 3d effect like the iOS camera app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

The standard camera app has a control that allows user to choose "video", "photo", "square", etc.  I know how to do most if it, but how do I get the cells on the edges to look as if they curl away from the screen?

I know how to use a transform, but that will just make them tilt, right?  How is it that the things look curved on the camera app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look curved to me.

Looks like a mixture of a 3D perspective transform. Rotating around the y axis. And a gradient at the edges of the screen to make the labels seem to fade away as they get to the edge.

Each label still looks straight. But the combination of he transform and the gradient gives the illusion that it is.

Comment: Even if you're wrong about what's really happening, I think you're right that this idea is close enough.  (and I agree that it probably is, just a gradient plus a tilt).  Thanks.